# Are there any Clang Static Analyzer checkers for sqlite issues?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

The Clang Static Analyzer used by Xcode uses checkers to identify warnings and errors in source code. I'd like to use a checker to detect when sqlite is used with `sqlite3_prepare_v2` being called without calling `sqlite3_finalize`.

Here is a list of existing checkers.

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html

And here is a list of potential checkers.

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/potential_checkers.html

Are there any checkers out there specific to sqlite which could address this issue? Is there another way to automatically detect missing/unbalanced calls?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No way.

Only you can do is, make sure you have written the `sqlite3_finalize` inside the `sqlite3_prepare` block instead of writing outside. This will handle `sqlite3_prepare` failure issues.

```
if(sqlite3_prepare(dbfile,query,-1,&statement,0)==SQLITE_OK)
{
   int res=sqlite3_step(statement);
   result=res;
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

If you are wtitten `sqlite3_finalize` outside the `sqlite3_prepare` block, it will cause issues while `sqlite3_prepare` statement fails.

Please look at this example: [Accessing a SQLite Database with C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/378808/Accessing-a-SQLite-Database-with-Cplusplus)

Comment: In this code is does not put the finalize call in the prepare block. It instead does it after like this. `if(stmt) sqlite3_finalize(stmt);` Does that make sense?

Comment: I have included more details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Clang Static Analyzer for that, you can find it in https://github.com/XSecurity/XSecurity